Navigate to a new screen in Flutter and firebase
I am havin a problem in my login page code.Whenever I click in login, it do not go to any other page the error says that trying to cast a _Map<String, dynamic> to a Map<String, String>, but i cant find the solution.
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'; import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'; import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/autho/user_text_field.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_five.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_four.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_one.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_six.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_three.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_two.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/userProfile/profile.dart';

//import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart'; class Login extends StatefulWidget { const Login({super.key});

@override State<Login> createState() => _LoginState(); }

class _LoginState extends State<Login> { //text edditing controllers final passWordController = TextEditingController(); final emailController = TextEditingController();

// sign user in methode Future<void> loginUser() async { try { final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email: emailController.text.trim(), password: passWordController.text.trim(), );

  // Handle successful login (optional)   print('Login successful!');    // Navigate to Diagnostic page after successful login (assuming this is the desired behavior)   Navigator.pushReplacement(     context,     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfile()),   ); } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {   if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {     print('The user account does not exist.');   } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {     print('The password is invalid.');   } else {     print(e.message);   } } catch (e) {   print(e.toString()); // Handle other exceptions }

}

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Scaffold( appBar: AppBar( /leading: IconButton( icon: const Icon( Icons.chevron_left, color: Color(0xFF032272), size: 40, ), onPressed: () {}, ),/ title: Text( 'LogIn', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF032272), fontSize: 30), ), centerTitle: true, ), body: Container( width: double.infinity, height: double.infinity, decoration: const BoxDecoration( image: DecorationImage( fit: BoxFit.cover, image: AssetImage("assets/images/background_image.png"))), child: SingleChildScrollView( scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, child: Container( padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 200, 0, 0), child: Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [ const Text( "Email", style: TextStyle( color: Color(0xFF032272), fontSize: 22, ), ), const SizedBox(height: 10), Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [ Container( width: 340, decoration: BoxDecoration( color: Colors.white, border: Border.all( width: 3, color: const Color(0xFFA9BCFE)), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), ), child: //hintText: 'example@example.com', MyTextField( controller: emailController, hintText: 'example@example.com', obscureText: false, ), ), const SizedBox( height: 30, ), //Container(), ], ), const Text( "Password", style: TextStyle( color: Color(0xFF032272), fontSize: 22, ), ), const SizedBox(height: 10), Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [ Container( width: 340, decoration: BoxDecoration( color: Colors.white, border: Border.all( width: 3, color: const Color(0xFFA9BCFE)), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), ), child: MyTextField( controller: passWordController, obscureText: true, hintText: '********', ), ), TextButton( onPressed: () {}, child: const Text( "forgot password", style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF032272), fontSize: 14), textAlign: TextAlign.end, ), ), const SizedBox( height: 30, ), ], ), Center( child: Container( padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 25, 0), width: 300, height: 50, child: ElevatedButton( onPressed: () { loginUser(); }, style: ButtonStyle( backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all( const Color.fromRGBO(3, 34, 114, 1)), padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(5)), shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))), ), child: const Text( "Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 27), ), ), ), ), const SizedBox( height: 30, ), Row( children: [ const Text( "Don't have an account ?", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17), ), GestureDetector( onTap: () {}, child: Text( "Sign Up", style: TextStyle( fontSize: 23, color: Color.fromRGBO(3, 34, 114, 1), ), ), ), ], ), ], ), ), ), ), ); }

Future<void> login() async { try { FirebaseAuth.instance .signInWithEmailAndPassword( email: emailController.text.trim(), password: passWordController.text.trim(), ) .then((userCredential) { FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('user_answers') .doc(userCredential.user!.uid) .get() .then((value) { Map<String, String> answers = value.data() as Map<String, String>; String question_0 = answers['question_0']!; String question_1 = answers['question_1']!; String question_2 = answers['question_2']!;

      if (question_0 == 'answer1' &&           question_1 == 'answer1' &&           question_2 == 'answer1') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarOne()),         );         ////! goto page one       } else if (question_0 == 'answer1' &&           question_1 == 'answer1' &&           question_2 == 'answer2') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarOne()),         );         ////! goto page one       } else if (question_0 == 'answer1' &&           question_1 == 'answer2' &&           question_2 == 'answer1') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarTwo()),         );         ////! goto page two       } else if (question_0 == 'answer1' &&           question_1 == 'answer2' &&           question_2 == 'answer2') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarTwo()),         );         ////! goto page two       } else if (question_0 == 'answer2' &&           question_1 == 'answer1' &&           question_2 == 'answer1') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarThree()),         );         ////! goto page three       } else if (question_0 == 'answer2' &&           question_1 == 'answer1' &&           question_2 == 'answer2') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarFive()),         );         ////! goto page five       } else if (question_0 == 'answer2' &&           question_1 == 'answer2' &&           question_2 == 'answer2') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarSix()),         );         ////! goto page six       } else if (question_0 == 'answer2' &&           question_1 == 'answer2' &&           question_2 == 'answer1') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarThree()),         );         ////! goto page three       } else if (question_0 == 'answer3' &&           question_1 == 'answer1' &&           question_2 == 'answer1') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarThree()),         );         ////! goto page three       } else if (question_0 == 'answer3' &&           question_1 == 'answer1' &&           question_2 == 'answer2') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarFive()),         );         ////! goto page five       } else if (question_0 == 'answer3' &&           question_1 == 'answer2' &&           question_2 == 'answer1') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarFour()),         );         ////! goto page four       } else if (question_0 == 'answer3' &&           question_1 == 'answer2' &&           question_2 == 'answer2') {         Navigator.pushReplacement(           context,           MaterialPageRoute(               builder: (context) => const UserNavigationBarSix()),         );         ////! goto page six       } else {         log('No specific page founded');       }

////////// }); }); } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) { if (e.code == 'user-not-found') { log('The user account does not exist.'); } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') { log('The password is invalid.'); } else { log(e.message.toString()); } } catch (e) { log(e.toString()); // Handle other exceptions } } }

this is my login page
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'; import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_five.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_four.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_one.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_six.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_three.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/pages/resumes/navigationbar/navigation_bar_two.dart'; import 'package:mini_proj/asma/userhome/home_screen_one.dart'; import 'package:path/path.dart'; import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'; import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class TreatmentReadyScreen extends StatelessWidget { final Map<String, String> answers;

TreatmentReadyScreen(this.answers, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance; final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(   appBar: AppBar(     title: Text('Treatment Plan'),   ),   body: Center(     child: Column(       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,       children: [         Text(           'Your treatment is ready!',           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),         ),         SizedBox(height: 20),         ElevatedButton(                      onPressed: () async {// Get the currently signed-in user             final user = _auth.currentUser;              // Save answers to Firestore with user ID             await saveUserAnswers(user!.uid, answers);             /*Navigator.pushReplacement(               context,               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => determineHomeScreen(answers)),             );*/             // Determine and navigate to the recommended home screen             final recommendedScreen = await determineHomeScreen(answers);             if (recommendedScreen != null) {               Navigator.pushReplacement(                 context,                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => recommendedScreen),               );             } else {               // Handle no recommendation found               ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(                 SnackBar(                   content: Text('No recommendation found in collections'),                 ),               );             }           },            child: Text('Start'),         ),       ],     ),   ), );

}

// Function to determine target home screen based on answers (replace with your logic) Widget determineHomeScreen(Map<String, String> answers) { final stressLevel = answers['question_0'];

// Question 3 (Concentration) final concentration = answers['question_3'];  // Question 4 (Focus Environments) final focusEnvironments = answers['question_4'];  // **Logic Breakdown (Considering All Three Questions):** if (stressLevel == 'answer1' &&     concentration == 'answer1' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer1') {   return UserNavigationBarOne(); } //2 else if (stressLevel == 'answer1' &&     concentration == 'answer1' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer2') {   return UserNavigationBarOne(); } //3 else if (stressLevel == 'answer1' &&     concentration == 'answer2' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer1') {   return UserNavigationBarTwo(); } //4 else if (stressLevel == 'answer1' &&     concentration == 'answer2' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer2') {   return UserNavigationBarTwo(); } //5 else if (stressLevel == 'answer2' &&     concentration == 'answer1' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer1') {   return UserNavigationBarThree(); } //6 else if (stressLevel == 'answer2' &&     concentration == 'answer1' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer2') {   return UserNavigationBarFive(); } //7 else if (stressLevel == 'answer2' &&     concentration == 'answer2' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer1') {   return UserNavigationBarThree(); } //8 else if (stressLevel == 'answer2' &&     concentration == 'answer2' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer2') {   return UserNavigationBarSix(); } //9 else if (stressLevel == 'answer3' &&     concentration == 'answer1' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer1') {   return UserNavigationBarThree(); } //10 else if (stressLevel == 'answer3' &&     concentration == 'answer1' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer2') {   return UserNavigationBarFive(); } //11 else if (stressLevel == 'answer3' &&     concentration == 'answer2' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer1') {   return UserNavigationBarFour(); } //12 else if (stressLevel == 'answer3' &&     concentration == 'answer2' &&     focusEnvironments == 'answer2') {   return UserNavigationBarSix(); } return Text('Unidentified Recommendation');

} Future<void> saveUserAnswers(String userId, Map<String, String> answers) async { // Create a reference to the collection in your Firestore database final collectionRef = firestore.collection('user_answers');

// Generate a unique document ID (not needed if using user ID) // final documentId = collectionRef.doc().id;  // Create a map containing the user ID and answers final data = {   'userId': userId,   'answers': answers, };   // Save the data to Firestore await collectionRef.doc(userId).set(data);

}

}

This is the page where i store answers.
so in my project after user answer some questions when first enter the app the app keeps his answers so when he login again it take him to same places but the problem is when it dont do anything it told me that the user is signin but nothing change with navigation

Could you attach the error message too?

Try using Map.from()

the map is causing the problem ... he error says that trying to cast a _Map<String, dynamic> to a Map<String, String>, but i cant find the solution aIm alreadt using strings i tried map.from() but it give the same prob
